# It possible to get the height of the ion-footer?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to get the initial window height minus the ion-footer height.
I succeeded but getting the window height still I have the footer height.
It possible the get the height of the ion-footer ionic2 element?

> I don't need to get the ion-content height

```
<ion-footer>
  <button type="submit" form="loginForm" ion-button block class="rnb-button" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Log In</button>
</ion-footer>
```

TS

```
this.gridHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

What I need

```
this.gridHeight = window.innerHeight - footerHeight;
```

thanks.

Comment: what have you tried, and what didn't work?

Comment: I'm trying the set the ion-grid height to become equal to ion-content height after the keyboard opening. because once the keyboard is opened the ion-content height changed the solution is window.innerHeight minus the ion-footer height

Comment: yes, but i mean, what code have you tried for getting footer height? and how were the results not fitting your expectation?

Comment: I didn't tried any code to getting the ion-footer that y I'm asking this question because I don't have any idea how to get the ion-footer height. just I get the window height using window.innerHeight

Comment: Give us the code where you have the ion-footer declared. HTML and TS, please.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the reference to the content to get the height of the footer using the [`contentBottom`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#contentBottom) property:

> `contentBottom`: A number representing how many pixels the bottom of
>   the content has been adjusted, which could be by either padding or
>   margin. **This adjustment is to account for the space needed for the
>   footer**.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    if(this.content) {
      console.log(`Footer height: ${this.content.contentBottom}`);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is just a recommendation but instead of using `window.innerHeight` you should use the `platform` to get that information because:

> Behind the scenes the `platform` uses the `window.innerWidth` and
>   `window.innerHeight` but using this method is preferred since **the
>   dimension is a cached value, which reduces the chance of multiple and
>   expensive DOM reads**.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
      console.log('Width: ' + platform.width());
      console.log('Height: ' + platform.height());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How could I do this from within a custom component? When I try to use `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;` .. and then log it out, I get undefined.

Comment: I think you can't do that. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to do it...

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom draggable drawer component the takes a footer-type position, for this I need to know the value of `content.contentBottom` from within the component... There must be a way to do it without passing content as an input because `ion-footer` does the same.

Comment: @juliusbangert do you mean something **[like this](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/)**?

Comment: Yes, I am adapting the concepts in that tutorial to be more generic such as I want it to automatically work with or without a tab bar.